# svnserve.conf authentication not worked

Tags: svn

I can setup Subversion server. I can commit change. The only thing I am not sure is to set up the basic authentication with svnserve. Here is the tutorial I followed:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html#tsvn-serversetup-svnserve-4

Based on the tutorial, I edited the 2 files: svnserve.conf and passwd, and restarted the apache server. But the authentication still cannot work.

Even if I set:

> anon-access = none

and restart apache, I **can** still read svn files and commit change from Eclipse.

Have I missed any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using apache to serve your repository, you need to read the next chapter [SVN server using Apache](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-apache.html).
The documentation that you read is only when you are using svnserver to serve your subversion repository using the `svn://` protocol.

Comment: Ok. thanks for your reminder that there is no need to restart apache when dealing with svn protocol. 

I think I am exactly dealing with svn://, As said, I have set anon-access = none.. it should never commit change without authentication in Eclipse. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. Few things to check: 1. Did you restart svnserver after updating the config? 2. Check if Eclipse is previously configured with user authentication already. Simple way to do that is to either do svn log on the 'supposedly not able' committed changeset and see what user was used for commit. Or right-click on your project and select *Properties* and then check the Team->SVN setting.

Answer (score 1):

svnserve is completely independent from Apache - it's a stand-alone service, so restarting Apache won't do anything. In fact, the point of svnserve is that you don't need Apache (and that's also why it uses svn:// URLs instead of http:// URLs).

If you want to use Apache, you'll want to look at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-apache.html instead.

Comment: I tried using Eclipse to import SVN project and commit change, I think Eclipse use exactly svn:// rather than http://. As http:// cannot commit change at least. I have set anon-access = none.. it should never commit change without authentication in Eclipse. Am I right?